# AWS CLI create multiple users

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I am trying to create multiple users using the AWS CLI. This is just an exercise in learning.
I get different errors depending on what changes I make. After a bit of searching, I changed the encoding and used file:// which elimated the Invalid JSON received errors.
I've tried this with a json file that is ASCII encoded and only one user.

```
aws iam create-user --cli-input-json file://aws-ec2.json --profile MyProf
```

I get:

```
Parameter validation failed: Invalid length for parameter Path, value:
0, valid range: 1-inf Invalid length for parameter
PermissionsBoundary, value: 0, valid range: 20-inf Invalid length for
parameter Tags[0].Key, value: 0, valid range: 1-inf
```

If I add another user, so change the UserName line to "MyEC2","SecondEC2", it just gives me `Invalid JSON received`.

Here's the JSON I am using:

```
{
    "Path": "",
    "UserName": "MyEC2",
    "PermissionsBoundary": "",
    "Tags": [
        {
            "Key": "",
            "Value": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

I know I'm doing something wrong, I just can't figure out what it is!

Comment: Well, the question didn't post the way it looked when I wrote it!!!! SHOULD have separated,  If I add another user, so change the UserName line to "MyEC2","SecondEC2", it just gives me Invalid JSON received. Here's the JSON I am using:.    { "Path": "", "UserName": "MyEC2", "PermissionsBoundary": "", "Tags": [ { "Key": "", "Value": "" } ] }

Comment: Site-question: Why are you providing empty tags and an empty PermissionsBoundary? If you don't want to provide the values, simply leave them out of the JSON. You could just use `aws iam create-user --user-name foo`

Comment: I tried that, and received the Invalid JSON error. I'm trying to create more than one user. Perhaps using the JSON file is not the correct method. I haven't tried a loop.

Comment: Are you saying that `aws iam create-user --user-name foo` (without involving a JSON file) gave an error? It should work as-is. The `create-user` command will only create a single user, so if you wish to create multiple users you would need to call it multiple times.

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't clear. That works just fine; to create a single user. I'm attempting to create multiple users from one command. aws iam create-user --user-name foo will create one user named foo. aws iam create-user --user-name foo1,foo2 will create one user named foo1,foo2.  My question is how to create multiple users. Maybe I should have written my question more clearly.

Comment: You can only create **one user** per call to `create-user`. If you wish to create multiple users, call the command multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you John. No one had anything to add. A friend of mine, networking person, suggested that I copy the command into Excel, concatenate the columns and then copy and paste the commands into the CLI.

I was hoping for a different response, but as I wrote in my question, this was just an exercise in learning. Your answer is an answer, and apparently a correct answer.

Thanks again for your time.